# ValueError: unsupported pickle protocol: 3 (python-2.7.6 and opencv -3.0.0 version in Ubuntu 14.04)

Tags: python, pickle, opencv3.0

åI am  trying to run a program from https://github.com/JunshengFu/driving-lane-departure-warning

when I try to run the code, I get these below error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "lane.py", line 85, in <module>
    mtx, dist = load_calibration(calib_file)
  File "/home/ramakrishna/driving-lane-departure-warning-master/calibration.py", line 78, in load_calibration
data= pickle.load(file)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 1378, in load
return Unpickler(file).load()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 858, in load
dispatch[key](self)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 886, in load_proto
raise ValueError, "unsupported pickle protocol: %d" % proto
ValueError: unsupported pickle protocol: 3
```

I am new to python.

Answer (score 0):

The code is trying to read data from a binary file written in a format that is specific for Python 3. You are using Python 2.7, so you get an incompatibility error.
You'll have to either use Python 3 or modify the data file to have it using protocol 2.

Comment: How am I supposed to do it..? I tried to install python 3.but I am not able to do so as it has python 2.7 in it default.

Comment: You can have both python 2 and python 3 installed on your machine. The command `python` usually defaults to v2 in older OS, but you can still use either one with the commands `python2` and `python3` respectively.

Comment: Python 3.6.3rc1 (default, Sep 22 2017, 13:56:28) 
[GCC 4.8.4] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>

Comment: How to go back to the directory.?

Comment: Ok got it. Thankyou so much.

Comment: $ sudo apt-get install numpy
[sudo] password for xxx: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package numpy

Comment: Try `sudo apt-get install python3-numpy`

Comment: $ sudo apt-get install python3-numpy
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
python3-numpy is already the newest version.
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libbonobo2-0 libbonobo2-common libgconf2-4 libgnome2-0 libgnome2-bin
  libgnome2-common libgnomevfs2-0 libgnomevfs2-common libidl-common libidl0
  liborbit-2-0 liborbit2
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 33 not upgraded.

Comment: -3537:~/PycharmProjects/Lanedect/advanced_lane_detection-master$ python3 line_fit_video.py 
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "line_fit_video.py", line 1, in <module>
    import numpy as np
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'